# Issue With Photo from Gallery Rotated 90 Degrees and Small

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bitmap, android-camera

I have an issue where when the profile picture is chosen from the phone's gallery, it rotates 90 degrees. This persists even when I close and then reopen the app. In addition, the profile picture is much smaller in size and I cannot seem to increase its size. If there is a way to increase the size that would be great. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
        btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_profile) as Button
        imageview = findViewById<View>(R.id.profile_image) as ImageView

        val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)

        var listImages : Array<File>? = null
        listImages = wallpaperDirectory.listFiles()

        if(listImages != null && listImages.size!! > 0){

            val img2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listImages[0].absolutePath)

            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, img2)
            round.isCircular = true
            profile_image.setImageDrawable(round)

        }
        else {
            val img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.profile_image)
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, img)
            round.isCircular = true
            profile_image.setImageDrawable(round)
            println("hit hit hit")

        }

    //    Profile Image
    private fun showPictureDialog() {
        val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action")
        val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Select Photo From Gallery", "Capture Photo From Camera")
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems
        ) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> choosePhotoFromGallary()
                1 -> takePhotoFromCamera()
            }
        }
        pictureDialog.show()
    }

    fun choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
    }

    fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data: Intent?) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode && requestCode == GALLERY)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                val contentURI = data.data
                try
                {
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, contentURI)
                    val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
                    round.isCircular = true

                    val path = saveImage(bitmap)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    imageview!!.setImageDrawable(round)

                }
                catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode && requestCode == CAMERA)
        {
            val thumbnail = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, thumbnail)
            round.isCircular = true
            imageview!!.setImageDrawable(round)
            saveImage(thumbnail)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }

    fun saveImage(myBitmap: Bitmap):String {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
        wallpaperDirectory.deleteRecursively()

        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        Log.d("fee",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
        {

            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs()
        }

        try
        {
            Log.d("heel",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
            val f = File(wallpaperDirectory, ((Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis()).toString() + ".jpg"))
            f.createNewFile()
            val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                arrayOf(f.getPath()),
                arrayOf("image/jpeg"), null)
            fo.close()
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath())

            return f.getAbsolutePath()
        }
        catch (e1: IOException) {
            e1.printStackTrace()
        }

        return ""
    }
    companion object {
        private val IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts"

    }

    //    Profile Image
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out-I forgot to put in `val rotatedBitmap = bitmap.rotate(90F)` after var bitmap to rotate it